# What is the difference between login.keychain and system.keychain?

Tags: keychain

Why not just have one? Is it because of unprivileged user accounts? Also what is a good official documentation page about them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system keychain is shared by all users on the current system. The system uses it to store your Wifi passwords, for example: when you login with a different account you thus still have access to the Wifi.

The login keychain can only be accessed by the current (owning) user.